# Scala play with reactivemongo, not working

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to follow along this [tutorial](https://spr.com/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-scala-play-part-1/) and I can't get reactivemongo to work:

This is my error:

```
  UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.reactivemongo#play2-reactivemongo_2.12;0.11.7.play24: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.reactivemongo:play2-reactivemongo_2.12:0.11.7.play24 (/Users/jwan/Desktop/programming/scala_play/rest-api/build.sbt#L12-20)
```

This is my `built.sbt`:

```
name := """rest-api"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.7.play24",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)

// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.example.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "com.example.binders._"
```

And this is my `application.conf`:

```
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Configuration

play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"

mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/getting-started-play-scala"
```

I can't get `sbt run` to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivemongo/play2-reactivemongo.

Required scala version is 2.11 for reactivemongo 0.11.7.play24.
Try 0.13.0-play26 for scalaVersion := "2.12.4" and play 26.

libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.13.0-play26"